# HDP 2.2 manual installation namenode format - wrong number of parameters?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I am installing Hortonworks Data Platform 2.2 manually on CentOS 6.5 64bit from RPM. During formating a namenode Insufficent parameters error is "thrown"

Those are instructions according to manual:

```
Format and Start HDFS
1. Execute these commands at the NameNode host machine:
su - hdfs
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/../hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
namenode -format
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/../hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh -
-config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start namenode
```

But during format command:

```
[root@virtual ~]# su - hdfs
[hdfs@virtual ~]$ /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/../hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh namenode -format
Usage: hadoop-daemon.sh [--config <conf-dir>] [--hosts hostlistfile] [--script script] (start|stop) <hadoop-command> <args...>
```

It doesn't pass through parameters check:

```
# Runs a Hadoop command as a daemon.
#
# Environment Variables
#
#   HADOOP_CONF_DIR  Alternate conf dir. Default is ${HADOOP_PREFIX}/conf.
#   HADOOP_LOG_DIR   Where log files are stored.  PWD by default.
#   HADOOP_MASTER    host:path where hadoop code should be rsync'd from
#   HADOOP_PID_DIR   The pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
#   HADOOP_IDENT_STRING   A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default
#   HADOOP_NICENESS The scheduling priority for daemons. Defaults to 0.
##

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop
usage="Usage: hadoop-daemon.sh [--config <conf-dir>] [--hosts hostlistfile] [--script script] (start|stop) <hadoop-command> <args...>"

# if no args specified, show usage
if [ $# -le 1 ]; then
  echo $usage
  exit 1
fi
```

I am not sure if this is bug in script or in manual ...

Any hint would help

Thx

Comment: Hortonworks is advising you post about this issue on their forums : https://twitter.com/hortonworks/status/557954315986276352 http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/forum/installing-hdp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting the NameNode, you can use the following command run as the 'hdfs' admin user:

```
/usr/bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

For starting up the NameNode daemon, use the hadoop-daemon.sh script:

```
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/../hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

"-config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR" is an optional parameter here in case you want to reference a specific Hadoop configuration directory.